# toad does not connect to DB on wifi

Tags: database, wifi, toad

I am not able to connect to DB using my home WiFi, but when I try using dongle I am able to connect. 
Any configuration I need to do so as to connect using WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but it may be a difference in your network adapter settings. Connect using the one that works and explore the properties of the adapter. Select the IPv4 properties and look at all of the property values including all of those behind Advanced buttons too. Compare these to the adapter that does not work. This is not a Toad or Oracle question per se.